# dbWriteTable with geometry (point) type to MariaDB

Tags: r, mariadb, r-sf, rmariadb

Working with `sf` objects in `R`, as well as tables in `MariaDB` with `geometry` (in this case `point`) columns, I'm struggling to efficiently move data between the two (`sf` object to `MariaDB` table and vice-versa).

*Note I'm using the `RMariaDB` package to connect to `MariaDB`, and have defined my connection here as `consdb`.*

Example data:

```
library(sf)
pnt <- data.frame( name = c("first", "second"),
                   lon = c(145, 146),
                   lat = c(-38, -39) )
pnt <- st_as_sf( pnt, coords = c("lon", "lat") )
```

**Trying to write sf object directly**

Ideally, I'd like to be able to write sf objects like this directly to `MariaDB` using `dbWriteTable` or `dbAppendTable`. At the moment, that gives what look like compatibility errors.

If I try with `dbWriteTable`:

```
dbWriteTable(consdb, "temp", pnt, temporary=TRUE, overwrite=TRUE)

# Error in result_bind(res@ptr, params) : Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field [1416]
```

Or by creating the table first:

```
dbExecute(consdb, "CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE temp (name VARCHAR(10), geometry POINT)")
dbAppendTable(consdb, "temp", pnt)

# Error in result_bind(res@ptr, params) : Unsupported column type list
```

**Trying to convert to point type on insert**

If I were inserting with a SQL insert query, I'd use `PointFromText` like so

```
INSERT INTO temp (name, geometry) VALUES ('new point', PointFromText('POINT(145 38)', 4326));
```

So I tried using that to send the data as a string. I wrote a couple of functions to convert the `sf` geometry column into an appropriate string column:

```
# to convert 1 value
point_to_text <- function(x, srid = 4326) {
    sprintf("PointFromText('POINT(%f %f)', %i)", x[1], x[2], srid)
}

# to apply the above over a whole column
points_to_text <- function(x, srid = 4326) {
    vapply(x, point_to_text, srid = srid, NA_character_)
}
```

Used that to turn the `sf` object into a `data.frame`

```
for_sql <- data.frame(pnt)
for_sql$geometry <- points_to_text(for_sql$geometry)
```

The geometry column is now a character column like: `PointFromText('POINT(145.000000 -38.000000)', 4326)`

Using `dbWriteTable` would just create a text column so I try creating the table, then using `dbAppendTable`:

```
dbExecute(consdb, "CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE temp (name VARCHAR(10), geometry POINT)")
dbAppendTable(consdb, "temp", pnt)

# Error in result_bind(res@ptr, params) : Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field [1416]
```

**Something that works, but seems silly**

I can get this to work if I create a temporary SQL table, change the column to text, insert the data from R, convert the column in SQL, then append that to the original SQL table. It seems ridiculously convoluted, but just to show that it works:

```
# create temporary table
dbExecute(consdb, "CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_geom LIKE temp")

# change the geometry column to text
dbExecute(consdb, "ALTER TABLE temp_geom MODIFY COLUMN geometry TEXT")

# add the data to the temporary table
dbAppendTable(consdb, "temp_geom", for_sql)

# add a new point column
dbExecute(consdb, "ALTER TABLE temp_geom ADD COLUMN geom_conv POINT")

# convert strings to points
dbExecute(consdb, "UPDATE temp_geom SET geom_conv = PointFromText(geometry, 4326)")

# drop the old column and replace it with the new one
dbExecute(consdb, "ALTER TABLE temp_geom DROP COLUMN geometry")
dbExecute(consdb, "ALTER TABLE temp_geom CHANGE COLUMN geom_conv geometry POINT")

# append the data from the temporary table to the main one
dbExecute(consdb, "INSERT INTO temp SELECT * FROM temp_geom")
```

Are there any solutions others use for this, or anything that might solve the problem of passing data between `sf` objects and `MariaDB` tables?

EDIT TO ADD: As per comment from @SymbolixAU, I've now tried the following

```
st_write(
    obj=pnt, # the sf class object, as created above
    dsn=consdb, # the MariaDB connection
    layer="temp", # the table name on MariaDB
    append=TRUE,
    layer_options=c('OVERWRITE=false', 'APPEND=true')
)

# Error in result_bind(res@ptr, params) : 
  Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field [1416]
```

Comment: Have you tried `sf::st_write()` directly? For example this works for me when writing to Postgres: `sf::st_write( obj = sf, dsn = consdb, layer = tbl, append = TRUE, layer_options = c('OVERWRITE=false', 'APPEND=true' ) )`

Comment: Thanks for the tip @SymbolixAU I just gave it a try with no luck. I'll edit the post to add it as an attempt.

Comment: Should your coords be in the order "lon","lat", rather than "lat","lon"? (You have  latitude of 145, which I think is a miatake)

Comment: Good spot @SymbolixAU yes that's a mistake. Unfortunately it doesn't fix the problem. Interestingly I can get `st_write` to write a new table (rather than append), but the geometry values get converted to something odd. In this case eg: "010100000000000000000043c00000000000206240"

Comment: That's Well-Known Binary, which is the binary representation of the geometry. It's a standard way of storing the data.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a bit of a hacky solution to this. It's not ideal, but I think it might be good enough.

Since the `sf` package can convert a geometry column to a WKT string with `st_as_text`, and `MariaDB` can do the reverse with `ST_GeomFromText`, I can use those to get things working.

One problem is that the function call I want to pass to `MariaDB` (something like `ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 2)')` can't be passed to any of the usual table write functions like `dbAppendTable` because they convert the function call to a text string (I assume by enquoting it), so I have to create my own insert query and call it with `dbExecute`.

Here's the function I've come up with, the intention of which is to play the role of `dbAppendTable`, when the object to write is an `sf` object.

```
sf_dbAppendTable <- function(conn, name, value, srid = 4326) {
    
    # convert the geometry columns to MariaDB function calls
    sfc_cols <- vapply(value, inherits, NA, "sfc")
    for(col in which(sfc_cols)) {
        value[[col]] <- sprintf(
            "ST_GeomFromText('%s', %i)",
            sf::st_as_text( value[[col]] ),
            srid
        )
    }
    
    
    # when inserting to sql, surround some values in quotes, except a few types
    # specifically exclude the geometry columns from this
    cols_to_enquote <- vapply(value, function(x) {
        if (inherits(x, "logical")) return( FALSE )
        if (inherits(x, "integer")) return( FALSE )
        if (inherits(x, "double")) return( FALSE )
        return( TRUE )
    }, NA) & !sfc_cols
    
    # set aside column names
    col_names <- names(value)
    
    # convert to a matrix
    value <- as.matrix(value)
    
    # it should be character
    if (typeof(value) != "character") value <- as.character(value)
    
    # enquote the columns that need it, except for `NA` values, replace with `NULL`
    value[ , which(cols_to_enquote) ] <- ifelse(
        is.na(value[ , which(cols_to_enquote) ]),
        "NULL",
        paste0("'", value[ , which(cols_to_enquote) ], "'")
    )
    
    # any `NA` values still remaining, also replace with `NULL`
    value[ is.na(value) ] <- "NULL"
    
    # create a single insert query
    sql_query <- sprintf(
        "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s);",
        name,
        paste(col_names, collapse = ","),
        paste(apply(value, 1, paste, collapse = ","), collapse = "),(")
    )
    
    # execute the query
    dbExecute(conn, sql_query)
    
}
```

This seems to be working for me, but I'm sure it's nowhere near as robust or efficient as something like `dbAppendTable` would be. For one thing I'm using a single query string which won't work well for large queries, and won't be as efficient as the `LOAD DATA INFILE` method some packages manage to leverage.

If anyone has a better solution, I'd still love to hear it.